# AWS S3 File upload using Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload an image to aws s3 using javascript. But when i attempt to upload it, I'm getting the following error.

```
Failed to load https://demoapp.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/IMG_2484.JPG: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Code :

```
<input id="file-chooser" type="file"/>
<button id="upload-button">Upload</button>
<p id="results"></p>
```

Javascript :

```
<script>
var credentials = {
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXX'
};
AWS.config.update(credentials);
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

// create bucket instance
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'demoapp'}});

var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
var results = document.getElementById('results');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var file = fileChooser.files[0];
    if (file) {
        results.innerHTML = '';

        var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file, 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': '*'};
        bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';
        });
    } else {
        results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
    }
}, false);
```

I configured the CORS as follows.

[CORS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GatLg.png)

Comment: Did you configure CORS for bucket?

Comment: The error looks like  a permissions problem on your S3 bucket configuration.

Comment: Yes i have configured it.

Comment: It's an XML ...?

Comment: Yes. i attached a screenshot of that configuration file with the question.

Comment: I take it "demoapp" is not really your bucket name?  Because that bucket exists, but its region is not `us-west-1` as shown in the error.  It's also not in `us-west-2` as shown in your code.  It's also interesting that the code and error you are showing are referencing two different regions.  Any ideas on why that might be happening?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - Really sorry for that. That error should be us-west-2. I'll update it.

Comment: @NimeshaBuddhikaPeiris be sure the error you are showing is exactly the error generated by your code -- don't just edit it to make it consistent.  If the error originally shown were accurate, that would explain the problem -- the error thrown by S3 if you were accessing the wrong region would not likely be pass the CORS pre-flight check.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you so much. I used a wrong region. I re check and change the region to ap-southeast-1 and then it worked for me. Thank you one again.

Answer (score 0):

The error `... Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource...` suggests a CORS misconfiguration, but in this specific case, the pre-flight check fails for a different reason: the request was not being sent to the correct S3 regional endpoint for the bucket.

S3 is a global service, but each individual bucket is constrained to exist in one specific region of S3.  All regions are aware of the correct location for all buckets, but are not able to access them.  Only the region that actually contains a particular bucket has access to that bucket, so requests arriving at other regions due to misconfiguration can't be processed.

When a request is sent to the wrong region, S3 throws an error... sort of.  It actually returns a `30X` HTTP redirect response, but the redirect does not include the customary `Location` header, so it isn't a redirect that the browser can follow.

Perhaps more important for the issue at hand, that response also does not contain the CORS response headers necessary for a successful pre-flight check... so a request sent to a bucket properly configured for CORS support will still fail the pre-flight check if the request is being sent to the wrong S3 regional endpoint.